# Should you edit other people's answer with lower byte counts?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've often come across answers like this:

> ## Python3, 40 bytes
>
> ```
> i=0
> while i>10:
>     i+=1
>     print(str(i))
> ```

When you could golf it down to

> ## Python3, 33 bytes
>
> ```
> for i in range(10): print(str(i))
> ```

Should you edit it, or leave it how it is and leave a helpful comment?

Comment: Leave a comment, don't edit.